# MVC3 routing with subfolder structure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, subdirectory

I've been learning MVC3 a bit for a while and although I understand most of the basics, the routing is something I just can't seem to get a hang off. I'm not sure whether I'm doing/thinking it in a correct way and the other answers I've read on stackoverflow/google only seem to confuse me more.

Anyway here's the situation. I've got a solution (cleaned it up for this question), where I'd like to create a structure in my views folder to organize everything in a structure I've been using for my asp.net webforms projects.

[image: solution]

Anyway, I was wondering whether it would be possible to get this kind of structure, where I could organize all my partial views into a specific subfolder called UserControls in which there are more subfolders where I would group every partial view I'd need for a specific page.

Ideally, my Views folder would contain 2 folders: Pages and UserControls and everything I'd need would go into a subfolder, or a sub sub folder.

Okay so if this is possible, how would I start routing this? I've been trying multiple ways of getting any result but they all end up in a 404 errors.

If this is a wrong approach of me, what would be a better alternative?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe providing us code will actually warrant an answer.

Comment: I don't want code, this is a mockup solution, I just want to know whether what I'm trying to do is possible and what would be a good approach to achieve this

Comment: You are ever so helpful. Good thing some people actually bothered to read it all. Good day.

Comment: You asked if you could use subfolders but the routing you put together kept giving you 404s. I then asked for your code. You denied that request. I prefer not to make assumptions at your approach, since you have tried something I would like to see what you're doing wrong instead of just spoon feeding you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically, this is better served by grouping your partials in with the actual views like so:

```
/Other
    /Partials
         OtherPartial1.cshtml
         OtherPartial2.cshtml
    Index.cshtml
/Some
    /Partials
         SomePartial.cshtml
    Index.cshtml
    SomeOtherView.cshtml
```

Now, you can certainly do as you suggest, but it simply means that your helpers in other views have more text to write to get where they want to go:

IE.

```
 @RenderPartial("Partials/OtherPartial.cshtml")
```

VS

```
 @RenderPartial("~/Views/PartialControls/Other/OtherPartial.cshtml")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could manually return the view file for each actionresult or partialactionresult.

I'd also recommend changing "UserControls (PartialViews)" folder to just PartialViews.

e.g.

```
public PartialViewResult OtherPartialView1()
    {
        return PartialView("../PartialViews/OtherViews/OtherPartialView.cshtml");
    }
```